# Getting a 400 and "Invalid Input: groupDescription" when creating a group with special characters in the name/description

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I've tried with the java client, version `directory_v1-rev20201215-1.31.0` as well as direct REST calls, and I continue to get a 400 error.  I haven't tried a full permutation of special characters, but I know for sure that an equals sign will fail when in the name or description of a group.  There's gotta be a simple escaping/encoding that I need to do, but I sure haven't found the part of the documentation that mentions it!
I also know that using the Google UI to create a group works, so IT is doing the right thing to allow special characters through.

Here's some pretty stripped down code, in case it helps:

```
   public Group createGroup() {
      Directory directoryService = null;

      try {
         final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
         final JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

         GoogleCredentials credentials;
         try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)) {
            ServiceAccountCredentials saCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
            credentials = saCredentials.createDelegated(IMPERSONATION_ACCOUNT).createScoped(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
         }

         directoryService = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials))
               .build();

      } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
         log.error("Unable to initialize service", e);
      }
      
      Group group = null;
      try {
        String groupText = "ASDF = QWERTY";
        String email = "foo@bar.com";

         Group newGroup = new Group();
         newGroup.setName(groupText);
         newGroup.setDescription(groupText);
         newGroup.setEmail(email);

         group = directoryService.groups().insert(newGroup).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         log.error("uh oh", e);
      }
      return group;
   }
```

I've also tried various other escaping and encoding mechanisms, but everything still stays encoded when returning the group.  So, apparently I still haven't found the right one.  Any thoughts/tips?

**Update 1:**
In response to @ron-m below, I am able to create a group with those special characters via the admin interface:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#group",
  "id": "01fob9te1iak5t4",
  "etag": "\"TMv00O2ISW7vEPqlqGLVmYmFaDFMCNc2QQc0SLgd5dQ/i_JUX6L9OJm-W4jcyL1hB1TApGg\"",
  "email": "__-cwm--test--group--characters-iu-group@XXXXXXXXX",
  "name": "__ CWM < test = group > characters",
  "directMembersCount": "1",
  "description": "__ CWM < test = group > characters, but in the description",
  "adminCreated": false
}
```

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Name guidelines for groups**](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9193374?hl=en)

- When adding group names, and group descriptions to Google Workspace or another Google Cloud account, use the following guidelines

**Group names and descriptions**

- Names can be up to 73 characters long.
- Use names that make it easy to identify the group’s purpose.
- For groups created in the Admin console, names and descriptions can’t contain **equal signs (=)**, or **brackets (<,>)**.

---

This guidelines seems to be applicable as well when creating groups using [groups.insert()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/insert?hl=en).

I was able to create a group with special character other than the mentioned invalid characters (<,>,=).

**Sample Response Body:**

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#group",
  "id": "sample id",
  "etag": "sample tag"",
  "email": "sample@example.com",
  "name": "ASDF, QWERTY",
  "description": "",
  "adminCreated": true
}
```

**Admin Console:**

[image]

Comment: EDIT: Not sure how to better format here!

Apparently Google doesn't follow their own guidelines, because through the admin interface, I am able to create a group with all those characters:

`{
  "kind": "admin#directory#group",
  "id": "01fob9te1iak5t4",
  "etag": "\"TMv00O2ISW7vEPqlqGLVmYmFaDFMCNc2QQc0SLgd5dQ/i_JUX6L9OJm-W4jcyL1hB1TApGg\"",
  "email": "__-cwm--test--group--characters-group@XXXXXXX",
  "name": "__ CWM < test = group > characters",
  "directMembersCount": "1",
  "description": "__ CWM < test = group > characters, but in the description",
  "adminCreated": false
}`

Comment: Weird.  Maybe it's something entirely different, but I can create it from groups.google.com

Comment: thank you for clarifying that, it is indeed possible to create new groups with invalid characters using groups.google.com. But if you want to create groups using Admin SDK API, you need to follow the guidelines implemented in creating groups through admin console.